# Navigation component crash onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-menu, android-architecture-navigation

I have started to receive this crash in Firebase Crashlytics. It is quite scarce.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.navigation.q androidx.navigation.o.N()' on a null object reference
   at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(NavigationUI.java:13)
   at androidx.navigation.ui.MenuItemKt.onNavDestinationSelected(MenuItemKt.java:10)
   at xxx.main.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:9)
   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4203)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java)
```

The app´s code is standard. MainActivity:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

I wasn´t able to simulate this issue. The app´s related code hasn´t been changed between the version where it started and the version before.

It looks to me that the crash is in Navigation Component, because I have just updated Navigation Component version from 2.3.1 to 2.3.3.

I think there is an issue in this part of code which has changed between versions 2.3.1 and 2.3.2. There may be getCurrentDestination() null or getParent() null:

```
navController.getCurrentDestination().getParent().findNode(item.getItemId())
```

Check the diff https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/ca16b13764d67c8e4d97f446e6ff1d116ceb73c8%5E%21/#F1

I also found possibly related issue, where they suggest the issue is in the library. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65339630/11927523

Do someone know how this issue can be reproduced?

Comment: The only time the current destination would be null is if you had manually called `popBackStack()` somewhere in your code and then didn't handle when it returned false (as you must as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack)). Are you calling `popBackStack()` anywhere in your code?